# Cant access application with root context. Needs to give /LoginPage.jsp

Tags: java, tomcat, server, websphere

I have created a web project as EmployeeManagement.
In web.xml, I set

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginPage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I am deploying on Apache Tomcat 7.0, it is working fine with url

```
http://localhost:8080/EmployeeManagement/
```

And when I am deploying its war file in Websphere, I can't access it. I need the same thing with

```
https://wasdev/EmployeeManagement/loginPage.jsp
```

I need to remove loginPage.jsp from the url.

Comment: which version of websphere are you running?

Comment: I am not sure if this would help but you can check the http://www.coderanch.com/t/646633/Websphere/Websphere-file-running-servlet-referenced. Excerpt from the link, on the config you may need to check: "Our WebSphere system was set up with two servers types: IIS and IBM HTTP Server and one cluster. Under Manage Modules, when both servers and the cluster are applied the application runs as expected. "

Comment: The welcome-file has LoginPage.jsp, but you are using loginPage.jsp in the request. I'd suggest checking the case of the LoginPage.jsp in the welcome-file list.